# Format raw text (from Google Forms response) into rows and columns in Google Sheets and append sheet

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-forms, flatten, text-formatting

I have a Google Forms where I'm capturing data in the following format.

```
Name:Karslten [0023]
Level:1
You managed to complete:
Burpies:30
Squats:45
Bench:29
Crunch:43
TotalLoss: 981

Name:Jaeger [0119]
Level:3
You managed to complete:
Burpies:40
Squats:53
Bench:45
Crunch:53
TotalLoss: 1253
Name:Fostyne [0003]
Level:1
You managed to complete:
Burpies:24
Squats:38
Bench:25
Crunch:32
TotalLoss: 758
```

I would like to know if it will be possible to use Google Sheets formula to use the data and format it into rows and columns in a specific way.  One form entry can contain data for multiple persons.

The format I want to achieve should look like this and all new entries must be appended to the new result sheet.

[Screenshot for the format I want from Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDPaA.png)

Here is a [link to a dummy editable Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g6Tst1QoGb_BYA2FspyIXJnX17iVbM9kOxX4rks86WY/edit?usp=sharing) with the same data. I hope some knowledgeable people can help me achieve this.  Thanking you in advance.

Comment: between person 1 and person 2 there is an empty row. is that by intention, mistake or its just way it is?

Comment: sometimes it can happen there is no empty row in between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(
 'Form Responses 1'!B2:B&CHAR(10)&SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE('Form Responses 1'!C2:C, 
 "Name:", "×Name:"), "×"), "(.+:)", ))), CHAR(10))), "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. works exactly as I wanted.  If possible, could you break up the formula and explain the steps?

Comment: @NadeemMuhammad sure, we start by SUBSTITUTing `Name` with `×Name` adding the unique symbol for SPLIT cutting. the splitter string we combine with date from B column by adding new line `CHAR(10)` between them. next we use REGEXREPLACE with pattern (.+:) which translates as "remove everything before colon, colon included". then we TRIM it to make it uniform and remove trailing spaces if any. next we FLATTEN it into one single column and SPLIT it by new line `CHAR(10)`. IFERROR for removing errors if any. QUERY for removing blank rows if any. and ARRAYFORMULA to process the whole array.